# how to add a decimal to a float value Objective C

Tags: decimal, calculator

I am trying to create a calculator and I can't find the proper code to add a decimal to my current code... any suggestions?
This is how my number buttons work:

```
- (IBAction)number9:(id)sender {
number = number * 10;
number = number + 9;
_textBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number];}
```

And this is an example of how my methods work.

```
- (IBAction)multButton:(id)sender {
if (hiddenSum == 0) {
    hiddenSum = number;
} else {
    switch (method) {
        case 1:
            hiddenSum = hiddenSum + number;
            break;
        case 2:
            hiddenSum = hiddenSum - number;
            break;
        case 3:
            hiddenSum = hiddenSum * number;
            break;
        case 4:
            hiddenSum = hiddenSum / number;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }}
    method = 3;
    number = 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you have not provided your variables definition I can not help you, at least say where does the compiler raises an error and what are the type of the variables on that line so I can help you cast them.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cast an Integer to a Float value so you can use plus operator on them this will help, However I am not sure if you asked for a cast.

your code shows that number is an Integer and I am pretty sure that the result of calculations should be a float so hiddenSum would be a float if I am right,

> Here it is an example about how you may cast an integer to a float

`int number = 10;`

`float hiddenSum = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: number] floatValue]`

Answer (score 0):

How about you store the number as an `NSString` until you actually need the numerical value? Then you can just append each number the user type in or the decimal point to the end of the string. When you need the numeric value from the string, you can use `[number doubleValue]`.